# How to use Select with lists

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I am trying to do:

```
Select[minimus[[6]], #1[[2]] < (min[[6]] + emin[[6]]) &]
```

applied to all elements of `minimus`, `min` and `emin`. They all have the same Length, but `minimus` is a list of pair coordinates `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ..., {xN, yN}}` while both `min` and `emin` are lists of values.

I thought something like this would work:

```
Map[Select[minimus[[#2]], #1[[2]] < (min[[#2]] + emin[[#2]])&]&, Range[Length[minimus]]]
```

But it didn't...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps you can include a sample list with the expected output?

Comment: Anyway, maybe something like `Function[{x}, Select[minimus[[x]], #1[[2]] < (min[[x]] + emin[[x]]) &] & /@ Range@Length@minimus`. Or just `Table[Select[minimus[[x]], #1[[2]] < (min[[x]] + emin[[x]]) &], {x, Length@minimus}]`.

Comment: `Select[minimus[[6]]...` is selecting from **two** values, you sure ties is correct? See my answer if you need another thing.

Answer (score 8):

```
Pick[minimus, UnitStep[min + emin - minimus[[;; , 2]]], 1]
```

or a pure function that does the same thing:

```
pF = Pick[#, UnitStep[#2 + #3 - #[[;; , 2]]], 1] &;
```

Examples:

```
min = RandomReal[{0, 0.5}, 10^6];
emin = RandomReal[{0, 0.5}, 10^6];
minimus = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^6, 2}];

p1 = pF[minimus, min, emin]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.059911

```
p2 = Pick[minimus, Thread[minimus[[;; , 2]] < (min + emin)]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.988790

```
p3 = First@Transpose@Select[Transpose@{minimus, min, emin}, 
     #[[1, 2]] < (#[[2]] + #[[3]]) &]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 2.497177

```
p1 == p2 == p3
```

> True

**Update:** A variation suggested by @ciao in the comments is faster for large lists:

```
pFx = With[{tot = #2 + #3}, Pick[#, UnitStep[Subtract[tot, Transpose[#][[2]]]], 1]] &;

min = RandomReal[{0, 0.5}, 10^7];
emin = RandomReal[{0, 0.5}, 10^7];
minimus = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^7, 2}];

p1 = pF[minimus, min, emin]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.555083

```
p1x = pFx[minimus, min, emin]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.461842

```
p1x == p1
```

> True

Comment: Amazing... I'm awesome to give the slowest solution!

Comment: We've both been schooled!

Comment: @BlacKow and Quantum_Oli, thank you both for the votes.

Comment: I think you might find this a bit faster, particularly on large lists (at least it is on my machine): `pFx=With[{tot = #2+ #3}, 
  Pick[#, UnitStep[Subtract[tot, Transpose[#][[2]]]], 1]] &;` - oh, and +1 o/c

Comment: @ciao, thank you so much. It is  faster on my machine too.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach, using `Pick`:

```
min = RandomReal[{0, 0.5}, 10]
emin = RandomReal[{0, 0.5}, 10]
minimus = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}]

Pick[minimus, Thread[minimus[[;; , 2]] < (min + emin)]]
```

Comment: +1 Your approach is about twice faster than mine...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want to select all values from `minimus` such as its second element is less than sum of corresponding `min` and `emin`

```
RandomSeed[3141592];
minimus = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 2}];
min = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10];
emin = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10];
First@Transpose@
  Select[Transpose@{minimus, min, 
     emin}, #[[1, 2]] < (#[[2]] + #[[3]]) &]
```